# Закрыть popup по клику вне окна react

Tags: reactjs

Верстка popup готова, как функционал сделать не знаю. По клику на .b-popup наверное нужно закрыть  сам попап

```css
*{
    font-family: Areal;
}
.b-container{
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    color: #fff;
}
.b-popup{
    width:100%;
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.b-popup .b-popup-content{
    margin:40px auto 0px auto;
    width:100px;
    height: 40px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="b-popup">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        Text in Popup
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class OutsideAlerter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setWrapperRef = this.setWrapperRef.bind(this);
    this.handleClickOutside = this.handleClickOutside.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  setWrapperRef(node) {
    this.wrapperRef = node;
  }

  handleClickOutside(event) {
    if (this.wrapperRef && !this.wrapperRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.props.onOutside();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div ref={this.setWrapperRef}>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}

OutsideAlerter.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
};
```

Пример использования:

```
export class MyPopup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        visible: true
    }

 render() {
    if(!this.state.visible)
        return "";
    return(<div className="b-popup">
       <OutsideAlerter onOutside={() => this.setState({visible: false})}>
           <div className="b-popup-content">
                Text in Popup
           </div>
       </OutsideAlerter>
   </div>)
 }
}
```

В компоненте `MyPopup` лучше не возвращать пустоту, а не рендерить его вообще в том компоненте, где он будет отображаться, я сделал на скорую руку.

P.S. Авторство OutsideAlerter за [@Ben Bud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1212039/ben-bud), я не стал сильно менять его код

UPD: Пример без обертки

```
export class MyPopup extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        visible: true
    }

 render() {
    if(!this.state.visible)
        return "";
    return(<div className="b-popup" onClick={() => this.setState(visible: false)}>
           <div className="b-popup-content">
                Text in Popup
           </div>
   </div>)
 }
}
```

Comment: слишком усложнено, создавать обертку компонент, для того, чтобы закрыть popup

Comment: @stiv я дополнил ответ примером без обертки

Answer (score 0):

В самом попапе вам нужно добавить кнопку для его закрытия. По клику на сам попап, кроме кнопки которая его должна закрывать, никто закрытие не делает. Зачастую попап закрывают либо по кнопке либо по области за попапом (это и показано в примере). Но все же рекомендую еще кнопку добавить

```js
$(document).click(function(e){
  if ($(e.target).closest(".b-popup-content").length) return;
  $('.b-popup').hide();
  e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

```css
*{
    font-family: Areal;
}
.b-container{
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:30px;
    color: #fff;
}
.b-popup{
    width:100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.b-popup .b-popup-content{
    margin:40px auto 0px auto;
    width:100px;
    height: 40px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color: #c5c5c5;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b-popup">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        Text in Popup
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery не подойдет, нужно решение на reactjs, поэтому он и указан в тегах